# Ruby: How to generate lines of code inside a program?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, parslet

I am developing a parser in Ruby using the [parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/) library.

The language I am parsing has a lot of keywords that can be merged into a single parsing rule like this:

```ruby
rule(:keyword) {  
    str('keyword1')     |
    str('keyword2')     | 
    str('keyword2')     ... 

}
```

Is there a good way to generate this set of lines of code dynamically, by reading a text file with all the keywords? 
This would help me keep my parser clean and small,  making it easier to add new keywords without modifying the code.

The pseudo-code of what I want to embed inside the `rule(:keyword)` would be somethings like this:

```
File.read("keywords.txt").each { |k| write_line " str(\'#{k}\') "}
```

So far, the workaround I have found is to have a separate ruby program loading the parser code as:

```ruby
keywords = ["keyword1", "keyword2","keyword3"]

subs = {:keyword_list => keywords .inject("") { |a,k| a << "str('#{k}') | \n"} }

eval( File.read("parser.rb") % subs)
```

where the parser code has the following lines:

```
rule(:keywords){ 
   %{keyword_list} 
 }
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
rule(:keyword) {  
  File.readlines("keywords.txt").map { |k| str(k.chomp) }.inject(&:|)
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that is not generating code. For instance, the str() method is unknown to Ruby.. But I get the idea, I will update my question with a workaround I have came up with. Be welcome to comment on that ;)

Comment: @zml - why are you using `eval`?? The idea I'm suggesting is to write this code _inside `parser.rb`_. The beauty of DSL is that you can use pure ruby code and it will work as well...

Comment: I tried to use a fixed version of your code inside the rule as: `rule(:keywords){  File.read("keywords.txt").split("\n").inject(""){|a,k| a<<"str('#{k}')|\n"} }` but that does not seem to work because the keywords are not being detected by the parser

Comment: You might want to change `File.read` to `File.readlines`. `File.read` just returns a string, and `map` doesn't work with strings...

Comment: Rookie mistake, it turns out that File.readlines is generating `["keyword1\n", "keyword2\n", "keyword3\n"]`, changing that to  `File.read("keywords.txt").split("\n")` makes it work ! Thank you

Comment: @zml - sorry, `readlines` does not remove the line separator you need to do it yourself (using [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp)) - I've fixed it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't really need to "generate lines of code". As @Uri tried to explain in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442657/1157054), there's nothing special about the contents of that `rule` method; it's just plain Ruby code. Because of this, anything you can do in Ruby you can do inside that rule method as well, including read files, dynamically call methods, and call methods on objects.

Let me break down your existing code, so I can better explain how a dynamic solution to the same problem would work:

```
rule(:keyword) {
  # Stuff here
}
```

This code right here calls a `rule` method and passes it `:keyword` and a block of code. At some point, parslet will call that block and check its return value. Parslet might choose to call the block using [`instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec), which can change the context the block is being executed in to make methods not available outside the block (like `str`, perhaps) available inside it.

```
str('keyword1')
```

Here, inside the context of the rule block, you are calling a method named `str` with the string "keyword1", and getting the result. Nothing special here, this is just a normal method call.

```
str('keyword1') | str('keyword2')
```

Here, the `|` operator is actually just a method being called on whatever `str('keyword1')` is returning. This code is equivalent to `str('keyword1').send(:'|', str('keyword2'))`.

```
str('keyword1') |
str('keyword2') | 
str('keyword2')
```

Same as before, except this time we're calling `|` on whatever `str('keyword1').send(:'|', str('keyword2'))` returned. The result of this method call is returned to the `rule` method when it calls the block.

So now that you know how all this works, you can perform exactly the same operations (calling `str` with each keyword, and using the `|` method to "add up" the results) dynamically, based on the contents of a file perhaps:

```
rule(:keyword) {  
  File.readlines("keywords.txt").map(&:chomp).map { |k| str(k) }.inject(:|)
}
```

Breakdown:

```
rule(:keyword) { # Call the rule method with the `:keyword` argument, and pass
                 # it this block of code.

  File.readlines("keywords.txt"). # Get an array of strings containing all the
                                  # keywords

  map(&:chomp). # Remove surrounding whitespace from each keyword in the array,
                # by calling `chomp` on them. (The strings returned by
                # `File.readlines` include the newline character at the end of
                # each string.)

  map { |k| str(k) }. # Convert each keyword in the array into whatever is
                      # returned by calling `str` with that keyword.

  inject(:|) # Reduce the returned objects to a single one using the `|`
              # method on each object. (Equivalent to obj1 | obj2 | obj3...)
}
```

And that's it! See? No need to generate any lines of code, just do what the real code is doing, but do it dynamically!

Comment: I understand your idea and it seems perfect. However it is not working :/. This works:  `rule(:keyword) {  
    str('keyword1') | str('keyword2') | str('keyword3')  
 }` and your version does not work, although I understand why it SHOULD work..

Comment: Well, time to start debugging then. Obviously there must be something functionally different between the dynamic solution I provided, and  and the static one you were using before.

What do you mean by "not working" anyway? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am not getting an error. The input text is not parsed as it is supposed to be when using your solution, so I guess parslet is not detecting the generated lines..

Comment: Not sure what to say, other than to give you general debugging advice. Try to isolate the problem, and verify your assumptions.

I'd probably start by replacing `File.readlines` with a static array of strings to see if that might be the problem. If it's not, move on to recording the return value of each `str` call, and perhaps the return value the block itself. Find out what the difference is between the dynamic code and the static code. If nothing works and you're completely stuck, reduce the problem to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post a new question about it here.